# How to change return type based on optional object parameter

Tags: typescript, function, arrow-functions

How to create `{ a: boolean }` only if `aX` exist in the `obj` parameter

```
type IObjFunc = () => void

interface IObj {
    aX?: IObjFunc
    bX?: IObjFunc
    cX?: IObjFunc
}

interface IReturnData {
    a?: boolean
    b?: boolean
    c?: boolean
}

const func = (obj: IObj) => {
    const returnData: IReturnData = {}

    if (obj.aX)
        returnData.a = true
    
    if (obj.bX)
        returnData.b = true
    
    if (obj.cX)
        returnData.c = true

    return returnData
}

const test1 = func({ aX: () => undefined })

console.log(test1.a) // Pass
console.log(test1.b) // No error, should be error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkg8gIwFYDECuA7AxlAvFACgEo8A+KANwHsBLAEwCgGaNgIAnAMwEMtp5kUAN4MoYqNwAaAfgBcsRKkxZR4hDPkCl2VWKwaFydDoC+TFmy69+AJQjA07DABFuwbsN0S5UBFSoANhDcGF4IPn6BwaHiUFgR-kEhDGYMWFQYAM7AUJzKeIRUyJqKJLjkIrHpWTns9o4ubtyadg5Oru4FQqmxNJyFyAB0UkResXVtje7DBcDsaBBeXn0DSIPqo7Hj9e1N67Pzi7HL-QRFa-qbW2ITDR3cgzj4cwtM25NQt7vuKUzV2VA2NkAIwFPLYAhCCSSeTEMhQTB0CCcFgQOhQEyjNIZTJRQYBKgAcwIQOAwOGJAA9JSoAAFbiZTLYrJ4gnE0nkhBUmkAOSoUA47Co7AANFBMgALKhoALohDQQXCoA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `IReturnData` to be generic if input

```
type IReturnData<T extends IObj> = {
    [K in keyof T
      as K extends `${infer P}X` ? P // or another mapping expression of your choice, like `ReturnMapping[K]`
      : never
    ]-?: boolean;
} & unknown // <- makes generic unwrap immediately
```

and make your function generic as

```
const func = <T extends IObj>(obj: T): IReturnData<T> => {...}
```

Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mLvOAw